# Loop sentences using return

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, return, return-value, enumerate

Im trying to loop through sentences and tags_to_label contains array of position of words in the sentence e.g: Adam lemmington ate an apple so tag_to_label = [1 2] position of the nouns in the sentence. Here im trying to return 1 if the length of tags_to_label > 1 else 0 but my code only loops through one sentence, is there a way to loop through all the sentences?

```
for i, item in enumerate(tags_to_label): 
       if len(tags_to_label) > 1:
        return 1
       else:
        return 0
```

Comment: `return` will exit the function and that is why the loop is ending after one sentence. If you want to show the results then use `print(1)`  or `print(0)`, or, if you want to save the results, consider using a `list`. If it is still not working you should post the code or explain further

Comment: @A.H.M.Annur I tried using buffer = [] if len(tags_to_label) > 1: buffer.append(1) else: buffer.append(0) return buffer, but this just returns [0]. Is there any way i can fix this?

Comment: Check the indentation of the statement `return buffer`. It should be less than the indentation of `buffer.append(0)`